# country specific sources.list file?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository

i was trying to setup local repository so i did some entries comment and some of them deleted. now i don't want to create local repository for less storages.

i have searched on google for `sources.list` entries so i found some entries like :

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
```

and some entries like :

```
deb http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe multiverse
```

so it seems like there is defferent repository for different country. so , i am from india so is this possible to find repository for india only. where should i search. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can generate sources.list file from  http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/index.php

```
select your country --> select your version --> select checkbox for repository --> click on generate List
```

copy and paste generated list to `/etc/apt/sources.list` :

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then run command for update and upgrade the system.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Note : if you selected third party software’s PPA then you have to add GPG Keys that is listed in GPG Keys section.

Comment: http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/index.php link is broken

Comment: The link has not been actualized. So recent Ubuntu distributions are not included in the option list. Nevertheless, I am not sure if this would have an impact.

Answer (score 3):

Go to System Settings -> Software & Updates.

There you can find your Indian local mirror. This is "Download from" drop down menu.

[image]

You do not have to edit `sources.list` manually. It will be updated automatically.

But all mirrors contain same packages. I do not recommend to use country specific server pools, like `.in`. It randomly picks a server from the pool. Not all servers always work well. I recommend to pick up a server manually or use "Select Best Server" option.

Comment: -1: last para [citation needed].

Comment: @muru What are you talking about? I fixed lots of problems by switching from some Indian servers to some others. Local servers in many countries do not work very consistently. I won't look for these questions anyway.

Comment: I have never had problems with `in.archive.ubuntu.com`.

Comment: @muru These country specific pool pick up one server from the pool like `in`. If you are unlucky you can get to a non-working server. This happens in other countries too. I recommend to pick up a local server manually instead of using the pool.

Comment: And what do you imagine `archive.ubuntu.com` does?

Comment: @muru I reworded that.

Comment: To your re-wording: What do you imagine `archive.ubuntu.com` does?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28899/discussion-between-pilot6-and-muru).